# Convert object a to match format of object b and merge them JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I got two data structures in different formats.

The first:

```
{loginRememberMe: false, test: false}
```

The second:

```
[
  {
    Objectname: "loginEmail",
    value: "one"
  },
  {
    Objectname: "loginPassword",
    value: "two"
  }
]
```

I am trying to convert the first structure to match the format of the second structure and to then merge them.

This needs to be done using JavaScript / jQuery,

Comment: I've formatted your code as they would appear in language so that the structure is easier to see. Question for you: can you show us an example of 1) what the first data structure should look like after reformat, and 2) what the final data structure after merge should look like

Comment: Also show what you tried....this isn't complicated and the idea on this site is to help you with code you developed and have issues with, not write code for you

Comment: synthet1c understood the question correctly and his answer is enough to work out what I need. I am working on it now and will post results later. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In future please show the final structure you need to have. You cannot directly merge an Object with an Array.

```js
var first = {
  loginRememberMe: false,
  test: false
}

var second = [{
  Objectname: "loginEmail",
  value: "one"
}, {
  Objectname: "loginPassword",
  value: "two"
}]

var modifiedArray = addObjectKeysToArray(second, first);

console.log( modifiedArray );
console.log( second );
console.assert(second !== modifiedArray, 'both arrays should be different');

function addObjectKeysToArray(arr, obj) {
  // copy the arr so we don't modify the original
  var arrCopy = arr.slice(0);
  // loop through the object properties
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      // add to the copied array
      arrCopy.push({
        Objectname: key,
        value: obj[key]
      });
    }
  }
  return arrCopy;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am tweeking your anserw to my needs, and it looks like it will work for me. I will post results later

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
myArray.push({
    Objectname: Object.keys(myObject)[0],
    value: Object.keys(myObject)[1]
})
```

if you want to get this array:

```
[
  {
     Objectname: "loginEmail",
     value: "one"
  },
  {
     Objectname: "loginPassword",
     value: "two"
  },
  {
     Objectname: "loginRememberMe",
     value: "false"
  }
]
```

and your array of objects is called `myArray` and the object you want to merge into array is called `myObject`.

Check demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/k3yjcLz3/2/)